# change the format of json serialization for R dataframe in plumber api

Tags: r, json, dataframe, plumber

I have a data frame in R that i want to serialize into json in a particular format. Sample code:

```
df_t<-data.frame(c(453:458),c(1:6), row.names = NULL)
colnames(df_t) <- c("area", "price")
jsonlite::toJSON(df_t)
```

The format of output of above code is as below:

> [{"area":453,"price":1},{"area":454,"price":2},{"area":455,"price":3},{"area":456,"price":4},{"area":457,"price":5},{"area":458,"price":6}]

But the format I want is:

> {"area":[453,454,455,456,457,458],"price":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}

To get the format I require i have written this bit of code which gives me similar output to what i expect but enclosed in quotes:

```
paste0( '{', colnames(df_t)[1], ':', jsonlite::toJSON(df_t[,1]),  ',', colnames(df_t)[2], ':', jsonlite::toJSON(df_t[,2]), '}')
```

> "{area:[453,454,455,456,457,458],price:[1,2,3,4,5,6]}"

My question is that is there a better way to get the format I want? The dataframe is being returned from a R plumber api and so is using jsonlite serializer by default.

Comment: You're explicitly naming your `df` with `"453"` etc, I don't understand how you expect `"area"` out of that. It seems as if your `colnames(.)` is wrong, and then you need to disable `plumber`'s internal serialization and instead call `jsonlite::toJSON(., dataframe="columns")` yourself.

Comment: @r2evans sorry. I have rephrased the question now

Comment: To add to @r2evans points concerning the dataframe it seems you're working counter to the dataframe structure. A dataframe is a list of same length vectors, and lists lend themselves to the json structure much more readily. it could be that altering the default serialization is more work than simply converting the R data structure to a list format. `list(area = 453:458, price = 1:6) |> jsonlite::toJSON()`

Comment: @KentOrr I will try with list. thanks

Comment: @r2evans Please mention the code snippet jsonlite::toJSON(., dataframe="columns") in an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @KentOrr Please mention your "dataframe to list" workaround in an answer so that i can upvote it.

Comment: I think @KentOrr's comment is much better than disabling default serialization and doing it yourself. Far more direct and elegant.

Comment: Sure. I will accept @KentOrr 's answer if he posts one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json` and the `jsonlite` package lend themselves more readily to the `list` format.
It could be that altering the default serialization is more work than simply converting the R data structure to match.

I would suggest something along the lines of

```
df_t<-data.frame(c(453:458),c(1:6), row.names = NULL)
colnames(df_t) <- c("area", "price")

df_t_list <- list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df_t)) {
  df_t_list[[i]] <- df_t[ , i]
}
names(df_t_list) <- c("area", "price")

jsonlite::toJSON(df_t_list)
```